# Why MariaDB doesn't work properly after upgrading?

Tags: mariadb

I had mariaDB script that used to work, but after switching to new machine (and newer version of mariaDB: `10.4.17-MariaDB`) the script suddenly stopped working.

The version of mariaDB that I get with select version() in phpMyAdmin on older machine (local computer) is 10.4.10-MariaDB. The script also runs on remote server with version 10.3.29-MariaDB-cll-lve. But, with the new version, the script doesn't work.

Here is the script that doesn't work properly:

```
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT IF(caseProcessed IS NOT NULL, caseId, NULL)) >4 
                        THEN concat(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(caseProcessed IS NOT NULL, caseId, NULL)), " cases")
                        ELSE ""
END AS nOfCases
```

After examining that part in MySQL Workbench, I noticed that result is BLOB, and if I change the line `ELSE ""` to `ELSE null`then the result is BLOB if condition is satisfied, and otherwise it is null.

What should I do to fix it? I understand that some scripts cannot work in older versions of MariaDB, but it is really silly that script that used to work on previous version cannot work with updated MariaDB.

Here is what I get as result in MySQL WorkBench. There is no error, the script just always returns empty string instead of real result.

[image]

Any advice how at least I can downgrade to 10.4.10-MariaDB?

Comment: Was your DBMS always mariaDB or did yo move from MySQL to mariaDB

Comment: Yes, it was always mariaDB. It is silly that the script still runs on server machine, and I have  just checked it's version. It is: 10.3.29-MariaDB-cll-lve

Comment: Ok, so "Does not work" is really very unhelpful! Does it generate Errors? Does it give a different result? Does it crash out of hand? What does Does not Work really mean

Comment: Yes it gives different result. If you take a look at the script expected result is jus to count rows where 'caseProcessed' is not null and to show that number. If number is greater than 4 it should return 5 Cases, otherwise it should return an empty string.

Comment: And yes, as I explained, it doesn't generate any error. But just returns false results.

Comment: Maybe you shoudl show us the 2 different results

Comment: I added a screenshot of the new result. I cannot give you the old result, because it was on the older machine. But you can just imagine  that it should write for example '21 Cases'.